# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property webBrowser1

Tags: c#

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.ShowDialog();

    string chatvar;
    chatvar = textBox1.Text;
    string chat;
    chat = "/chat";
    string chaterino = "http://twitch.tv/" + chatvar + chat;
    Form3.webBrowser1.Navigate(chaterino);

}
```

Apparently, the problem is with

```
Form3.webBrowser1
```

I tried looking for an answer here but nothing helped me.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between static and non-static? `webBrowser1` is an instance field - it belongs to an *instance* of `Form3`. So which instance do you want to use? Now think about how to tell the compiler that. Note that searching for your exact error message (minus `webBrowser1`) found 449 hits on Stack Overflow - have you checked them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `f3.webBrowser1.Navigate(chaterino);` because the error which you got indicates that `webBrowser1` is a non static field, method or property.

To use such a non static stuff, you need to make use of an object.

In your case you've already created an object, `Form3 f3 = new Form3();`

If `f3.webBrowser1.Navigate(chaterino);` doesn't work, then you will have to figure out in which class has been `webBrowser1` defined, create an object of that particular class and use in place of `f3`.

Answer (score 0):

You already have reference to `Form3` - that's the `f3` instance, so you can use it directly to access its properties:

```
f3.webBrowser1.Navigate(chaterino);
```

Of course for this to work you should make sure that the `webBrowser1` property or field is `public`.